# Conflicting MQTT clientId when running application from multiple pods

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, mqtt, aws-iot

When 1 of my 6 pods connected to the MQTT in AWS IoT Core another pod will also try to connect with the same clientId in the env config of the node server. This will lead to the disconnection and reconnection to the new pod. This event happens continuously, and the topic `$aws/events/presence/connected/#` received multiples messages in 1 second. This make the MQTT client unstable.

[image: connection code]

I tried to lock the connection of the MQTT client on just 1 pod by storing the status of the client connection in the database.

[image]

However, this leads to another problem that when I call an API to publish 1 topic using the MQTT client the API can not know which pod has the MQTT client connected.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, they are hard to read, impossible to search and useless for those that need to use a screen reader. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: Please add details for your setup. What kind of mqtt clients do you have? What is your broker? What are your MQTT settings?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just leave the `clientId` value empty and let the client assign a random one?

Comment: I am using AWS IoT Core and there is a special "Thing" that can pub/sub to all topic. So I want my client to connect to the clientId of that special "Thing". If the client assign a random one, maybe it's not certain to connect to that `clientId`